# Handle locks when stored procedure is executed concurrently in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure written in SQL Server which has some logic derived by joining various tables in the database and finally the end result is inserted into a table.

This stored procedure is being called from front end using .Net application api by various users .

If only one user is performing some operation, it's taking some 20 seconds to complete the operation.

If multiple users are performing the operation, then it's hanging and taking almost more than 20 mins to complete.

I have tried to understand the locks getting backend and tried to set hints `WITH(NOLOCK)` and some other options but not able to resolve it.

How to handle the locks effectively when concurrent execution is happening?

Comment: What you've identified is a problem with concurrency. What you've seemingly assumed is that this is caused by locks. 20 seconds is a pretty damn long time, and what you may be seeing is just the server running out of resources when having to do this a few times in parallel. How have you established it's a locking issue, and not a more boring issue with poorly performing queries in general?

Comment: Would need to see your SP and the execution plan (https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) to be able to offer assistance.